# Sending LiveVideo to Http server using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I want to stream a video over http server i can do this easily with ffmpeg exe using below command

`ffmpeg -i abc.mp4 -f mpeg1video -vf "scale=640:480" -r 20 https://localhost/XXXX`

but i want to achieve same result using ffmpeg library instead of exe. i can easily play/record video using ffmpeg libraries.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ
 its very easy to just press downvote button and edit a question without reading it complete. I am writing a C++ Application that will use FFMPEG people are using other languages too. C++ tag was correct

Comment: There's no concrete  c++ code mentioned in your question that you're stuck with, hence I removed the tag. And I read your question to the end BTW.

Comment: I need solution in C++ only what if people will start suggesting solution in other  languages.

Comment: So let's start with: _What have you tried?_ Stack Overflow is not your _"Gimme teh Codez plz"_ shopping mall.

Comment: this is a solution for remux the video https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/remuxing_8c-example.html after modifying it littlebit i can make video player and recorder. but i dont know how i can send  AVPacket to http server

Comment: You can start studying the c code in the ffmpeg library (exe) how they actually send AV packets to a specific server as specified from the command line. That's what I would start with.